# Prove that a curve is not regular

Tags: differential-geometry

Anny suggestions to start the following problem?

Let $\vec{x}:I\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a curve. Show that if there is a strictly monotone sequence $(a_k)\subset I$ that converges in $I$ such that $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ $\vec{x}(a_k)=\vec{u}$, then $\vec{x}$ is not a regular curve.

The hint says it helps to show that $\vec{x}(\lim_{k\to\infty} (a_k))=\vec{0}$, but I can't see how this is useful.

I know that for a regular curve $\vec{x}'(t)\neq 0$ $\forall t\in I$ and maybe we can derive something from the fact that $\vec{x}(a_k)=\vec{u}$, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $x$ is differentiable (if it's not, then it's certainly not regular). Let $a = \lim_k a_k$. Then the velocity vector of $x$ at $a$ is

$$ x'(a) = \lim_{y \to a} \frac{x(y) - x(a)}{y-a}.$$

From basic analysis we know that since $a_k \to a$ we have $$ x'(a) =\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{x(a_k) - x(a)}{a_k - a}.$$

We are given that $x(a_k)=u$ for every $k$, and since $x$ is continuous we know $x(a) = \lim_k x(a_k)=u$ as well. Thus the top of this fraction is zero for every $k$; so the velocity is $\lim_{k\to \infty} 0 = 0$.

Comment: Just noticed that I forgot to thank you for your answer.